# Sitecore Controller rendering not able to load the view on postback

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am working on Sitecore MVC controller. I have created a controller “EventController” that have two actions “AllEvents” and [HttpPost] “SelectedYear”  , one view “\Views\Event\AllEvents.cshtml”

“AllEvents” is attached with Sitecore controller rendering when I do publish preview  from the content item page is loading with data and there is no problem.  “All Events” page  have a dropdown
When I click on selected year the post back is going but the view is not loading as required and losing the RenderingContext also. The url is going to hit http://testPage/api/Event/SelectedYear  and image and css are not loading but data is there.

Below I have shared the sample code.

Please help me to fix the issue.

AllEvents.cshtml

```
<div>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectedYear", "Event", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm"}))
  {
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedYear, Model.mapLocationItemTypes, "-- Select Status --", new { id = "CategoryID" })
  }
 </div>
```

SelectedYear Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectedYear()
return View(eventCalender);

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert("HSecond")
            $("#CategoryID").change(function () {
                $('#TheForm').submit();
            });
        });

</script>
```

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Html.BeginForm()` you specify the controller and the action to post to. But in fact, you want to post to the same Url, load the same Item and call the `[HttpPost]` action instead. This is a little different between ASP.net MVC and Sitecore MVC. I've written a blog post on how to handle form posts with Sitecore MVC:

http://ctor.io/posting-forms-in-sitecore-controller-renderings-another-perspective/

Also I had a presentation about Sitecore MVC at the SUGCON this year where posting forms was a topic. You may also want to look at the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/aquasonic/sugcon2015-sitecore-mvc-advanced) or the [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3Gd1MW1WXI)